# Run-Time error 5 Points to an Add-in

Tags: excel, excel-2013, vba

I created an add-in with code that moves data around between workbooks, sorts data, removes duplicates, and saves the workbook. All of this is working fine. Then I added a line of code (This is the line: `Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1).Select` ) that I copied from another (unrelated) add-in. After inserting this code, When I went to close the workbook, I received the run-time error and the debugger points to a line of code from a sub in a different add-in. There is nothing in the new add-in that is connected to the add-in showing the error. Here is the code that the debugger shows as the issue:

```
Sub Delete_Master_Menu()
'
    On Error Resume Next
    Application.CommandBars(Menuname).Delete
    On Error GoTo 0

End Sub
```

The error is on this line: `Application.CommandBars(Menuname).Delete`

As indicated by the tag, I am using Excel 2013 now. Not sure if that makes a difference. We just upgraded from 2007.

Like I stated though, this code was working until I added the line indicated above. I still get the error even after removing that line. That was the only change that happened prior to receiving the error.

**EDIT: As I try different steps, I have discovered that this is happening even when I try to close a blank workbook (or any other workbook for that matter).**

**Update: I disabled the add-in that is causing the error, and the error has gone away. However, I need that add-in to work on hourly reports, so I need to understand why this is happening on how it can be corrected.**